# Protecting against Manipulating form input with Django Forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a question to protect attackers from manipulating form inputs.

Let's say I have a rental request from a customer. In Django, there is a `create_rental` URL, say `rent-website.com/customer/1/create_rental`.

Because in `urls.py`

```
url(r'^customer/(?P<pk>[0-9])/create_rental/'
    ,CreateRentalView.as_view()
    , name='customer_create_rental'),
```

The Django Form class has a `for_customer` attribute. Let's say in `forms.py` there is

```
CreateRentalForm(forms.Form):
    for_customer= forms.IntegerField(..., widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    rental_title = forms.CharField()
    #and so on and so forth
```

In views.py,

```
CreateRentalView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    def get_form(self):
        super(CreateRentalView, self).get_form()
        self.base_fields['for_customer'].initial = self.kwargs['pk'] #in this case 1
```

Finally, in templates, you will have the HTML

The question is, if the attacker changes that value to 2, then he can add it for a customer that he might not be serving.

Is there a way in Django to prevent or mitigate this?

Comment: Why do you want to protect attacker?  In this sort of thing the customer id shouldn't be a part of the url but it should be retrieved from the session.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of implementing your own logic regarding which objects each user can access, it has nothing to do with the framework itself.

Having said that, take a look at [Django Guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

> django-guardian is an implementation of object permissions for Django providing extra authentication backend.